# Struct initializer is inaccessible due to private protection level from its own file

Tags: swift

Using Swift 4, I have defined two structs in the same file, where one of them is private so this file is the only one that can access it. Also I'm relying on the struct's default/synthesized initializer i.e. I'm not explicitly defining one:

```
private struct A {
  private let string: String
  ...
}

struct B {
  func foo() {
    let a = A(string: "bar")
    ...
  }
}
```

However this will fail to compile with the following error:

> 'A' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

I don't want to have `A` accessible to other files, so I tried to work around it by making it `fileprivate` (which should be equivalent to `private` in this scenario), but the same compilation error will occur (and it still complains that the protection level is `private`).

Is there a way to keep this struct `fileprivate` and still get a synthesized initializer that exposes all uninitialized properties? i.e. `A.init(string:)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It turns out that the "private access level" complaint was regarding the `init`ializer, not the struct. The initializer's access level is only as accessible as the *least accessible* instance variable.

If I make the `string` instance variable anything other than `private`, the error goes away:

```
private struct A {
  let string: String
  // synthesized initializer:
  // init(string: String)
}
```

So given that `B` can now read `A`'s `string`, it can also access `A`'s initializer.

If `A` had another `private` property though, then again its initializer would become `private`:

```
private struct A {
  let string: String
  private let int: Int
  // synthesized initializer:
  // private init(string: String, int: Int)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t you then say that the initializer is only as accessible as the least accessible variable?

Comment: I just ran into this in a SwiftUI project and it was definitely perplexing behavior in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

You can define initializer. It will help you to keep this structure `private`. The main problem is `private let string` compiler automatically add initializer with private access level `private init(string: String)`.

For fix you have to define your own initializer

```
private struct A {
    private let string: String

    fileprivate init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }

    func foo() {}
}

struct B {
    func bar() {
        A(string: "baz").foo()
    }
}
```

Or you can use `fileprivate` access level for `string` property. In this case you don't need initializer.

```
private struct A {
    fileprivate let string: String

    func foo() {}
}

struct B {
    func bar() {
        A(string: "baz").foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the OQ says "how can I avoid expliciting an initializer"

Comment: In this case you should use `fileprivate` access level for `string` property. Please check my edited answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to address the error which can happen when working with SwiftUI structs.

Given this code will produce the same error since the variable is not initialized or the compiler does not know if that variable is guaranteed to have a value.

```
struct MyView: View {
    // Compiler: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ 
    // initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
    private var rows: [Int]

    var body: some View {
        Text("Some text")
    }
}
```

So you either make it optional, unwrapped or initialize with a value.

```
struct MyView: View {
    // Initialized
    private var rows = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Some text")
    }
}
```

When `MyView()` is instantiated the compiler will not complain.

```
struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler won't complain if you do that, but it won't allow you to inject anything on init either - your property is private, thus it won't be exposed in the generated initializer. The original question is "How can I avoid expliciting an initializer" - I'll edit it to make it clearer that I still expect that init to have parameters

Answer (score -2):

I Used

```
private let s: String = "Some value"
```

it works for me..